# How do I pass a json object to jade template?

Tags: node.js, pug

This may sound like a very basic question and it may be a very basic question. I have just started learning node and I am stuck at something I feel is very stupid.

I have a route defined as below

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res, next){
    res.render('control', { values: { p: "This is a paragraph" }});
});

module.exports = router;
```

The jade template named `control` is define as below

```
extends layout

block content
    each val, key in  values
        if key == "p"
            p= val
```

But this throws an error like below

```
E:\Projects\xyz\views\control.jade:4 2| 3| block content > 4| each val, key in values 5| if key == "p" 6| p= val 7| Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

TypeError: E:\Projects\xyz\views\control.jade:4
    2| 
    3| block content
  > 4|  each val, key in  values
    5|      if key == "p"
    6|          p= val
    7|
```

But if I change the `each` loop in the template as shown below, then everything works fine

```
extends layout

block content
    each val, key in  { p: "This is a paragraph" }
        if key == "p"
            p= val
```

How can I move the `{ p: "This is a paragraph" }` into the router?

Comment: Not sure why you get that error, it's working just fine for me. Is the code you're posting the exact code you're using? Because it looks like `values` may be undefined.

Comment: Double checked the actual code and whats posted here. It is exactly the same and still does not work. Could you provide a jsfiddle or something for your working sample?

Comment: Here's [a gist](https://gist.github.com/robertklep/cfb5174b21add2f322ba) (`express@4.13.1`, `jade@1.11.0`, `node@0.12.6` and `iojs@2.5.0`)

Comment: I do not seem to find any difference in your gist and my code. I still get the error

Comment: Did you try the gist standalone?

Comment: No. But I do not understand the difference. I have exact same code as your gist.

Comment: If you run it within a larger context, the context may be interfering somehow.

Comment: That's what I am thinking. Not sure how to track it down. I don't think my json object is passed into jade template at all

Comment: Can you check if `res.locals` or `app.locals` are defined?

Comment: How do I check that?

Comment: Quick and dirty: `console.log(res.locals, app.locals)` right before calling `res.render()`

Comment: I do not see anything in  the console tab of chrome developer tools.

Comment: It'll be logged in your terminal (from where you start the Node.js server).

Comment: I get an `undefined` there

Comment: Sorry, running out of ideas :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after lot of google and head scratching, it came down to mixing spaces and tabs in the jade view. Apparently jade does not like mixing spaces and tabs and start throwing nasty exceptions. Everything working fine after I removed all the tabs. Spaces are the way to go.